# .NET MAUI Entry keyboard does not hide

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard, maui

I have a very simple UI that has one entry control to enter phone number and a button. The entry control has a handler for removing border around it. When the entry control got focus, keyboard pops up. But when I try to tap outside the entry control such as on the screen empty area, the keyboard does not dismiss and the entry control does not lose focus. Also since the button is at the bottom of the screen, therefore, the soft keyboard hides it and there is no way to tap the button. The button can only be tapped if I press the Android device back button.

At present, I have not checked this behavior on an iOS device.

This was not a problem in Xamarin Forms though. I searched a lot on Internet and found that it is currently a bug in MAUI.

I tried to attach a tap gesture on the parent layout control and invoked platform-specific code to hide the keyboard but it seems the entry does not lose focus and in turn the tap gesture event is never called.

However, the entry control should lose focus automatically when I tap outside the entry control (such as on the screen) and the soft keyboard should automatically dismiss.

Please provide a workaround if there is any.

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: Does calling `Unfocus()` on the Entry close the keyboard?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With .NET8 `ContentPage` has `HideSoftInputOnTapped` attribute. If you set it to `true`, the keyboard will be dismissed touching anywhere on the page.

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             HideSoftInputOnTapped="True"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <Entry />
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

Known bug. Removing the focus sometimes helps. Sometimes you need to do Disable/Enable in sequence. (I go with the second).

If you want, you can read this for example:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12002

(Most disturbing part, considering this is know bug for half year+)

> We can leave the behavior how this is for now in NET7 and provide an
> API in NET8 that lets users toggle this behavior on/off for iOS and
> Android

Comment: Thank you H.A.H. Now I have switched back to Xamarain Forms :)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround solution

```
private async void OnShowKeyboardTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EntryInput.Focus();
   await Task.Delay(100); // Important to add delay here
   Helpers.KeyboardVisibility(true);
}

private async void OnHideKeyboardTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Helpers.KeyboardVisibility(false);
}

private void KeyboardVisibility(bool StateFocus)
{
#if ANDROID
if (Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus != null)
{
    if (StateFocus)
    {            
 Platform.CurrentActivity.ShowKeyboard(Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus);
    }
    else
    {       Platform.CurrentActivity.HideKeyboard(Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus);
        Platform.CurrentActivity.CurrentFocus.ClearFocus();
    }
}
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue. Here is how I solved it:

```
Entry entry = new Entry { };
    
void OnEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string text = ((Entry)sender).Text;            
    entry.IsEnabled = false;
    entry.IsEnabled = true;
}

entry.Completed += OnEntryCompleted;
```

Specifically, the .IsEnabled being set to false, when the Done button is pressed (entry.Completed), is what dismisses the virtual keyboard. This completely disables the entry field but retains the value that had been entered. I make sure to set .IsEnabled back to true so that the user can edit that field again.

Hope this helps.